# Convert nested list to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

My nested list that I’m trying to convert into a dictionary looks like this:

```
my_dict = {}
book_ratings = [["Ben"],["5", "0", "1", "4"], ["Sally"],["0", "7", "3", "3"]]
```

I’m trying to return names ["Ben"], ["Sally"] as the keys and the ratings ["5","0","1","4"], ["0","7","3","3"] as the values.

Hoping for the output:

```
 {"Ben": ["5," "0", "1", "4"], "Sally": ["0", "7", "3", "3"]}
```

Comment: Please can you edit the question to use normal quotes instead of smart quotes, or it is not valid syntax.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Have you looked into, for example, splitting the list into pairs, and then doing `my_dict[pair[0][0]] = pair[1]` for each pair? Or maybe using even and odd indices?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: `{l[0]:v for l, v in zip(book_ratings[::2], book_ratings[1::2])}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the structure of `book_ratings` is Name, List, Name, List, ... you can use this example to construct the dictionary:

```
book_ratings = [["Ben"],["5", "0", "1", "4"], ["Sally"],["0", "7", "3", "3"]]

i = iter(book_ratings)
my_dict = dict((a[0], b) for a, b in zip(i, i))

print(my_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'Ben': ['5', '0', '1', '4'], 'Sally': ['0', '7', '3', '3']}
```

---

Or:

```
my_dict = dict((a, b) for (a,), b in zip(book_ratings[::2], book_ratings[1::2]))
```

Comment: I also had your second idea myself, but I think that your first method with the iterator is the more efficient solution.

Comment: @alani Actually the second one appears to be more efficient, see the benchmark in my answer.

Comment: @superbrain I was thinking more about space than time, but thanks.

Comment: @superbrain Ambiguity in English, but "think" in this context related to opinion rather than belief about a fact... in my opinion it is (overall) the more efficient (because in terms of space, it certainly is)

Comment: @alani Oh, overall. Yes, I agree. Btw, both would be a lot faster if they were dict comps.

Answer (score 7):

Simple dict comp:

```
>>> it = iter(book_ratings)
>>> {k: next(it) for k, in it}
{'Ben': ['5', '0', '1', '4'], 'Sally': ['0', '7', '3', '3']}
```

Benchmark with the accepted answer's solutions (`f1` and `f2`) and mine (`f3`), three rounds, numbers are times in seconds so lower=faster:

```
2.31 f1
2.08 f2
1.39 f3

2.30 f1
2.03 f2
1.34 f3

2.30 f1
2.08 f2
1.31 f3
```

Benchmark code:

```
from timeit import repeat

book_ratings = []
for i in range(1000):
    book_ratings += [["Ben" + str(i)],["5", "0", "1", "4"]]    

def f1():
    i = iter(book_ratings)
    return dict((a[0], b) for a, b in zip(i, i))

def f2():
    return dict((a, b) for (a,), b in zip(book_ratings[::2], book_ratings[1::2]))

def f3():
    it = iter(book_ratings)
    return {k: next(it) for k, in it}

for _ in range(3):
    for f in f1, f2, f3:
        t = min(repeat(f, number=10000))
        print('%.2f' % t, f.__name__)
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iter` and some `zip` magic to get every other key. But since your keys are in lists and you just want the single value from them you'll need to use a dict comprehension:

```
book_ratings = [["Ben"],["5", "0", "1", "4"], ["Sally"],["0", "7", "3", "3"]]
my_dict = {k[0]: v for k, v in zip(*([iter(book_ratings)]*2))}
```

---

```
{'Ben': ['5', '0', '1', '4'], 'Sally': ['0', '7', '3', '3']}
```

Comment: It's the same concept as Andrej's answer just in one line instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with dict comprehensions without the need to define an empty dict:

```
book_ratings = [["Ben"],["5", "0", "1", "4"], ["Sally"],["0", "7", "3", "3"]]
new_dict = {book_ratings[i][0]:book_ratings[i+1] for i in range(0,len(book_ratings),2)}
new_dict
```

Output:

```
{'Ben': ['5', '0', '1', '4'], 'Sally': ['0', '7', '3', '3']}
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(book_ratings)) if i % 2 == 0` - you should check the optional third argument of `range` as you are looping over every item only to throw half of them away, instead of looping every 2.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion alani, I forgot about it, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
my_dict = {}
book_ratings = [['Ben'],['5', '0', '1', '4'], ['Sally'],['0', '7', '3', '3']]

i=0
while i<len(book_ratings):
  if not book_ratings[i][0].isnumeric():
    my_dict[book_ratings[i][0]] = book_ratings[i+1]
    i+=2
  else:
    i+=1

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Ben': ['5', '0', '1', '4'], 'Sally': ['0', '7', '3', '3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

one more solution, may be simpler for beginners

```
my_dict =  {}
book_ratings = [['Ben'],[5, 0, 1, 4], ['Sally'],[0, 7, 3, 3]]
for i, book in enumerate(book_ratings):
    if (i==0) or (i%2==0):
        try:
            my_dict[book[0]] = book_ratings[i+1]
        except:
            pass
        
print(my_dict)
```

prints

```
  {'Ben': [5, 0, 1, 4], 'Sally': [0, 7, 3, 3]}
```

Comment: `(i==0) or (i%2==0)` -- the first test there is redundant

Comment: yeah you are right,i forogt that 0%2 is also 0... i was thinking in my head that python would return None for that one.. idk why...